# Before / After Javascript issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on the currently codepen to display a hair treatment results

[CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/dhechler/pen/JviLA)

But as soon as I add it to my website, it does not work.

I made a fiddle, and seems like the following class is breaking the code (on the fiddle works fine but does not follow the mouse pointer on the movement).

```
.wrapper_estudio {
        width: 965px;
        margin: 81px auto 0px auto;
        padding-top: 100px;
    }
```

**EDIT**
More especifically, the `margin: 81px auto 0px auto;` or the `width: 965px;` value.

[DEMO (NOT JSFIDDLE)](http://anubis-cosmetics.com/test/test.html) -> **Check out this Demo to see what is exactly going on. Open console and uncheck the margin (or the width) on the div wrapper_estudio. Why does it work when margin is not set?**

[DEMO (JS FIDDLE)](http://jsfiddle.net/EAACu/)

```
$(function(){
    var isDragging = false,
        slide = $('.slide'),
        controls = $('.controls');
    $(".container").mousedown(function() {
        $('.container').mousemove(function(e) {
            var elemOffset = $(this).offset(),
                relX = (e.pageX / $(this).width()) * 100;
            console.log(relX);
            if(relX < 98){
                slide.css('width',relX + '%');
                controls.css('left',relX - 3 + '%');
            }
            isDragging = true;
            $(window).unbind("mousemove");
        });
    })
    .mouseup(function() {
        var wasDragging = isDragging;
        isDragging = false;
        $('.container').unbind("mousemove");
    });
  $('.container').mouseleave(function(){
    isDragging = false;
    $(this).unbind("mousemove");
  });
});
```

Comment: Both the codepen and jsfiddle links work for me. What browser are you using?

Comment: A little off-topic but that codepen is neat! And I like the cats too :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem lies in `relX = (e.pageX / $(this).width()) * 100;` where `e.pageX` gets the x position of the mouse relative to the left edge of the document as stated in the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/event.pagex/).

Now when you add the margins with css the `.container` acquires an offset from the left side resulting in something like in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DG7w4/) and the slider won't work correctly as happens in your website or in the fiddle you gave.

To solve this you need to modify the x coordinate like this:

```
relX = ((e.pageX-elemOffset.left) / $(this).width()) * 100;
```

What this does is subtracting the left offset of the image container from the distance from the left edge of the document thus returning the relative position of the mouse in the element.

So your final code should look like this:

```
$(function(){
    var isDragging = false,
        slide = $('.slide'),
        controls = $('.controls');
    $(".container").mousedown(function() {
        $('.container').mousemove(function(e) {
            var elemOffset = $(this).offset(),
                relX = ((e.pageX-elemOffset.left) / $(this).width()) * 100;
            console.log(relX);
            if(relX < 98){
                slide.css('width',relX + '%');
                controls.css('left',relX - 3 + '%');
            }
            isDragging = true;
            $(window).unbind("mousemove");
        });
    })
    .mouseup(function() {
        var wasDragging = isDragging;
        isDragging = false;
        $('.container').unbind("mousemove");
    });
  $('.container').mouseleave(function(){
    isDragging = false;
    $(this).unbind("mousemove");
  });
});
```

And here is the working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EAACu/1/)

Comment: It works perfectly. Otherwhise, If you see this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/EAACu/2/ you will see how they slide all at the same time. Is there any solution to make all them independent?